# Prove or disprove the following sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

Let $$x_n=\frac{1}{1+n^2}+\frac{2}{2+n^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{n+n^2}$$
be a sequence. Prove or disprove that the sequence converges.

Here's what I have done so far: I tried to find the lower and upper bounds for each term and found that $$\frac{1}{2}\le x_n \le \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2}; \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
I was hoping to show that it is a monotone sequence and bounded. Any hints without the use of integrals are much appreciated.

Comment: If your bounds are correct then you are essentially done by the squeeze theorem. Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Did you really mean $\frac2{1+n^2}$? Or did you mean $\frac2{2+n^2}$?

Comment: Ah yes! Now I wonder how could I have not seen that. Thank you.